# QHeaderView stylesheet for QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to customize appearance of header for my QTableWidget using stylesheet. I'm doing this way:

```
QHeaderView::section 
{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    font: 10pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}
```

It looks nice in Qt Designer and in it's preview mode, but when I'm running the program, header is created with default colour and font.

Qt version 4.7.2, OS Windows XP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've discovered that this problem appears only when I'm using `QTableWidget`. So the solution I found is to use `QTableView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you change stylesheet of parent widget's stylesheet, it both works for designer and running program.

For example, If I set headerview's style in tblPlatforms it is not working. But If I put headerview's style in platformFrame's stylesheet, it works!

[image: stylesheet of table headerview]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to solve this problem:
in the tablewidget's Base class construction func:
add this:
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("");
then it will works.
I don't know why,
but it works. ^_^